# Facebook sdk need to open on another Activity?

Tags: android

I am developing login screen .it consists of two buttons 
1. Login in with google and Login with Facebook.
My question is, suppose user press a facebook button in one activity facebook-sdk  need to open in another activity Or( another screen)and enter his/her details.Is that possible ??

Answer (score 0):

The user should not enter the username/password in your app, it should do it on the facebook login page provided by the sdk. So you don't need any other activity or screen, you can manage to do everything from the same activity.

This guide from facebook should be easy to follow.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/

Comment: Thanks for your info. I know that but, i need to use this Activity code in another screen .that's the reason why i am asking. is that possible to open i in another Activity??

Comment: I don't totally understand your questions, but yes, you can make a buton that says "Facebook" open a new activity, and then execute the code for the sdk

Comment: sorry. i will rephrase  my question. my application has two Activities . First activity has login with facebook button .If any user press this button he should navigate to second Activity .in second Activity there is a Facebook sdk code need to be Execute.  can you tell me how to put facebook sdk code in second activity??

Comment: why can't you execute the facebook sdk on the first activity?

Comment: Because , if facebook sdk execute on second Activity i can reuse this code in another Activity( i.e Another activity mean application has another activity called image selection Activity.) This Activity has a Login with facebook button .when ever user open this activity and click button  i first check the user is logged in with facebook or not .Because user can sign in with google aslo.

Comment: To do this, i need to write fb logic in another Activity .Instead of that i will write  fb sdk logic to launch in another activity(Second Activity) so that i can use this Second Activity logic  to Image selectionActivity( image selectionActivity can fetch the user photos from fb if he logged in with fb). if user not logged in with facebook.  Hope this i clear all u r doubts. why i am asking to open fb Sdk in another Activity

Comment: Don't write the logic to another activity, write it to a helper class with a static method for example

Comment: thank you. but, i think your explanation is not complete??